# Differentiable function in the normed space $\,\mathcal{C}[0,1]$

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $E=\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Let $f:E\rightarrow E$ defined by $f(x)(t)=\sqrt{|x(t)|}$. For which functions $x$ is differentiable?

Comment: Hint: where is $\varrho \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; \varrho(x) = \sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}$ differentiable?

Comment: Daniel in zero?

Comment: It looks like you misread, that's the one point where it isn't differentiable.

Comment: ok yes in $x\neq 0$

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming we are talking about real spaces. Also, you should have clarified the meaning of derivative (Fréchet vs Gâteaux), but I can answer anyway.

The set $U=\{x\in \mathcal{C}[0,1]: x(t)\ne 0\ \forall t\in [0,1]\}$ is open in $\mathcal C[0,1]$. The functional $f$ is Fréchet  differentiable on $U$ with the derivative given by 
$$Df_x(h)= \frac{\operatorname{sign} x}{2\sqrt{|x|}}\, h\tag1$$ Here $\operatorname{sign} x$ is well defined because $x$ has constant sign. The proof that 
$$f(x+h)-f(x)= Df_x(h) +o(\|h\|)\tag2$$
is not hard, using the fact that $1/\sqrt{|x|}$ is also in $\mathcal C[0,1]$.

It remains to show that $f$ is not even Gâteaux differentiable at $x\notin U$. Let $h$ be constant; since  $\|f(x+h)-f(x)\|\ge \sqrt{\|h\|}$ (look at what happens at a point where $x$ vanishes), the conclusion follows.

Comment: why $$f(x+h)-f(x)= Df_x(h) +o(\|h\|)\tag2$$ using the fact that $1/\sqrt{|x|}$ is also in $\mathcal C[0,1]$?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero By the Mean value theorem: $f(x(t)+h(t))-f(x(t))=h(t)f'(\xi)$ where $\xi$ is between $x(t)$ and $h(t)$. The function $f'(\xi)=1/(2\sqrt{|\xi|})$ is uniformly continuous on any compact set that does not include $0$. Use this to conclude that  $f'(\xi)-f'(x(t))\to 0$ as $\|h\|\to 0$, uniformly in $t$.

Comment: Hello @ju. I had trouble understanding what you write is that my definition of differentiable function is different:     **Note**: $f$ is differentiable in $a$ iff exist $Df(a)\in \mathcal{L}(E, F)$ so that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h||_F}{||h||_E}=0$$

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero The definition in formula (2) is  the same as in your comment. The notation $o(\|h\|)$ stands for something that, when divided by $\|h\|$, tends to $0$ as $\|h\|$ tends to zero.