# differentiable prove of product functions

Tags: calculus

Let $E, F$ normed spaces and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g:A\rightarrow F$, with $A$ open set in $E$, and defined $h:A\rightarrow F$ by $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$.  Suppose that $f$ es differentiable in $a\in A$, $f(a)=0$, and  that $g$ is continuos at $a$. Prove that $h$ es differentiable at  $a$, with $Dh(a)=g(a)Df(a)$.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
   && ||h(x)-h(a)-(g(a)Df(a))(x-a)||\\
     &=& ||f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)-(g(a)Df(a))(x-a)-g(x)Df(a)(x-a)+g(x)Df(a)(x-a)|| \\
   &=&  ||Df(a)(x-a)(g(x)-g(a))+g(x)[f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)]||\\
   &\leq&  ||Df(a)(x-a)||\,||(g(x)-g(a))||+||g(x)||\,||f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)||
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @Christopher I was trying the above but the last inequality is not true and that I can not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on your last line, which seems okay to me.

- I use the operator norm, denoted $|||\cdot |||$. $Df(a)$ has a norm since it is a continous linear map. So $||Df(a)(x-a)||\,||(g(x)-g(a))|| \leq |||Df(a)|||\,||(x-a)||\,||(g(x)-g(a))||$
- $g$ being continous, it is locally bounded around $a$, so (locally) $||g(x)||\,||f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)|| \leq C\,||f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)||$.

So we can divide by $||(x-a)||$ and get $$\begin{align}\frac{||h(x)-h(a)-Dh(a)(x-a)||}{||x-a||} \leq &|||Df(a)|||\,||g(x)-g(a)|| \\&+ C\frac{||f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)||}{||x-a||}\end{align}$$.

When $x\to a$ , the first term goes to zero because $|||Df(a)|||$ is a constant and $g$ is continous, and the second term goes to zero because of the differentiability of $f$.

Comment: you could write your arguments with other notation than that of the "or" is that I'm not quite understand that notation. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What notation do you use ? $y(x) = y(a) + Dy(a)(x-a) + \cdots$. What goes in the $\cdots$ ???

Comment: $f:E\to F$ is differentiable in $c$ iff $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{||f(x)-f(c)-Df(c)(x-c)||}{||x-c||}=0$$

Comment: all right, I will edit.

Comment: Justt the following second inequality is not true right? $$||Df(a)(x-a)(g(x)-g(a))+g(x)[f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)]||\leq  ||Df(a)(x-a)(g(x)-g(a))||+||g(x)[f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)]||\leq||Df(a)(x-a)||\,||(g(x)-g(a))||+||g(x)||\,||f(x)-f(a)-Df(a)(x-a)||$$ that was the problem in my proof

Comment: Yes, actually, all the terms concerning $f$ are real numbers, so the second axiom of a norm allows them to "get out" as absolute values.

Comment: $Df(a)(x-a)\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes ! Since $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$, $Df(a) : A \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks justt...excuse my abuse could help me with this exercise http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431059/differentiable-function-in-the-normed-space-mathcalc0-1 is that not quite understand the solution they gave me

Comment: Explain in a comment of that answer what part precisely you didn't understand.

Comment: when say The proof that 
$$f(x+h)-f(x)= Df_x(h) +o(\|h\|)\tag2$$
is consecuence of the fact that $1/\sqrt{|x|}$ is also in $\mathcal C[0,1]$.